# Find a version controlled project's root?

Tags: version-control, vc-mode

Trying to deduce a project root, using `vc` I'm getting errors, involving strange non-ASCII characters. I.e. invoking

```
(vc-find-root (expand-file-name (buffer-file-name (get-buffer "fname"))))
```

I get

```
eval: Wrong number of arguments: #[(file witness) 
" ...several non-ASCII characters ..."
)" [vc-ignore-dir-regexp locate-dominating-stop-dir-regexp file witness locate-dominating-file] 3 2751734], 1
```

in the Message buffer. I'm not sure if this is a problem related only to `vc.el` or more generally to my setup/machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Wrong number of arguments

`vc-find-root` must be invoked with two arguments: `(vc-find-root FILE WITNESS)`.

To get vc root use `vc-root-dir` instead:

> `vc-root-dir` is an autoloaded compiled Lisp function in `vc.el`.
>
> Return the root directory for the current VC tree.
>
> Return nil if the root directory cannot be identified.

And if you need the vc root of specified buffer:

```el
(let ((buffer (get-buffer "fname")))
  (when buffer
    (with-current-buffer buffer
      (vc-root-dir))))
```

Comment: Where WITNESS could be something like ".git"? Ok.?

Comment: @Mark Yes. `.git` or `.hg`. `vc-find-root` is used by vc backends and each backend pass it's own WITNESS.